# How to wait for app to end before processing next command in bat?

Tags: batch-file, wait

I'm trying to open DisplaySwitch to switch to internal, then open GOG Galaxy, then DisplaySwitch back to extend after GOG Galaxy has closed.

```
%windir%\System32\DisplaySwitch.exe /internal
cd /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\GOG Galaxy"
Start /W GalaxyClient.exe
%windir%\System32\DisplaySwitch.exe /extend
```

GOG Galaxy opens, but DisplaySwitch doesn't switch to internal. Where am I going wrong please?

Comment: Your question header does not seem to match the content. Are you asking why you are not switching to internal or how to wait for a process to complete before execution of the next one?

Comment: Sorry. I need DisplaySwitch to switch to internal. That doesn't happen. Once DisplaySwitch has switched to internal and app has opened (GOG Galaxy in this case), I need the bat to stop there until GOG Galaxy has closed, then it should continue with DisplaySwitch switching to extend. What is currently happening is GOG Galaxy opens, the DisplaySwitch side bar opens, but that is it. It doesn't switch to internal.

Comment: So you are saying that if you run `displayswitch /internal` from cmdline it does not switch to internal, or only in this script?

Comment: Only in the script, well sort of. If I remove the last line, then run the script it does switch to internal. What appears to be happening is it switches to internal, runs the app, then runs extend so it's doing everything instantly without waiting despite the /W switch. What I need is for it to run internal, run app but then stop until I have closed the app, and only then should it run extend.

Comment: I would first of all advise that you remove the ```Start /W ``` on line `3`. I would also try ```"%SystemRoot%\System32\DisplaySwitch.exe" 1``` for line `1`, and ```"%SystemRoot%\System32\DisplaySwitch.exe" 3``` for line `4`. I would also doubt that you'd need to change directory just to run the exectuable, so I'd also try removing line `2`, and having just ```%ProgramFiles(x86)%\GOG Galaxy\GalaxyClient.exe```. Without knowing what `GalaxyClient.exe` is, it is possible that is just a stub, which runs something else, if that is the case, as soon as the stub has done its work it will exit.

Comment: Thank you, but same result. If I test the script trying to open notepad instead however, it works! The issue then is the app I am trying to open is a stub as you mentioned. Question is then, how do I get this to work with a stub? Is it possible?

Comment: Did you determine whether your 'app' is a stub? _(a stub is essentially a small application which starts one or more processes)_. When you start it, it will run those processes then very quickly close. Because the exectuable you started has now finished, it will trigger your next command. Take a look at Task Manager, _(or if you have it, an alternative utility like Process Monitor, or Process Explorer)_, to find out exactly what is opened when you invoke `GalaxyClient.exe`, and you should be able to understand better.

Comment: Mofi, thank you, I have already changed code to Compo suggestion and file saved correctly. @Compo, thank you. Yes I can only assume it's a stub. I've looked at Task Manage and can see under app 'GOG Galaxy (32 bit) (2), then background processes 'Galaxy Client Helper Application' and 'GalaxyClient Helper Application'. From what you've explained I guess it's not possible then to get this working with stub?